# Unexpected NoMethodError after migration to add new column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, sti

I have a `player` model inheriting from a `user` model to share authentication logic (devise) with a 3rd model (`coach` that also inherits from user).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
class Player < User
end
class Coach < User
end
```

I'm trying to add a field to the `player` table when players register so I created a migration

```
rails g migration AddClubCoachEmailToPlayer club_coach_email:string
```

then ran the migration

```
rake db:migrate
```

for the file

```
class AddClubCoachEmailToPlayer < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :players, :club_coach_email, :string
  end
end
```

Schema as expected

```
  create_table "players", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "club_coach_email"
  end
```

Now, I need to add the field to /views/players/registrations/new

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  #...

  <div><%= f.label :position %><br />
    <%= f.radio_button(:position, "Striker") %> Striker
    <%= f.radio_button(:position, "Midfielder") %> Midefielder
    <%= f.radio_button(:position, "Defender") %> Defender
  </div>
  <div><%= f.label :club_coach_email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :club_coach_email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :profile_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :profile_name %></div>

 #...
```

and I sanitize params through this technique from devise wiki; in lib/player_sanitizer.rb I add the new field.

```
class PlayerParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer
  private
  def sign_up
    default_params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :profile_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :email, :grad_year, :position, :club_team, :formation, :club_coach_email)
  end
  def account_update
    default_params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :profile_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :email, :grad_year, :position, :club_team, :formation)
  end
end
```

This is what my application controller looks like

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
    dashboard_path
  end

  protected
  def devise_parameter_sanitizer
    if resource_class == Player
      PlayerParameterSanitizer.new(Player, :player, params)
    elsif resource_class == Coach
      CoachParameterSanitizer.new(Coach, :coach, params)
    else
      super
    end    
  end 
end
```

However, I must be missing some step because when I navigate to /players/sign_up I'm getting a   `NoMethodError in Players::Registrations#new`

```
undefined method `club_coach_email' for #<Player:0x00000109296be8>
```

Obvioulsy, here is where the trace is pointing

```
<%= f.radio_button(:position, "Defender") %> Defender
 </div>
 <div><%= f.label :club_coach_email %><br />
 <%= f.email_field :club_coach_email %></div>

 <div><%= f.label :profile_name %><br />
 <%= f.text_field :profile_name %></div>
```

What do I seem to not understand here?

Comment: What happens if you put in your view: <%= resource.class %> ? Does it say User?

Comment: no, it indicates Player

Comment: What about resource_name? What you got there when in the view?

Comment: That shows player as well. My thought is that is has something to do with the way I'm sanitizing the parameters with devise..

Answer (score 0):

As for me you're doing it too complex. From the information you gave there is no different functionality between this three different users types, therefore it will be easier to make all of them not through inheritance but with the [devise roles](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-a-default-role-to-a-User).

In this way you'll have One user model with three different roles (User, Player, Coach).

Or there is other way - using different models in "devise way":
`rails g devise User` + `rails g devise Player` + `rails g devise Coach`

After this you'll get three almost separate models each with all devise functionality and methods (for example: `player_signed_in?`, `current_coach`, `authenticate_player!` etc.).

Comment: This is an approach yes, but I'm still confused about my error.